# Adding Headers to a table using formattable in R

Tags: r, formattable

I would like to add headers entitled "Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3" and "Category 4" to a table, separated by a black line. I would like it to look like the picture attached. Please see the code for the table without the Categories/black lines between columns:

```
library(formattable)
data(mtcars)

df <- mtcars

formattable(df)
```

#### Desired plot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one with `kable` where can use `add_header_above` by passing a vector of key/value pair with `key` suggesting the name and value for the number of columns to be expanded

```
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
mtcars %>%
   kable() %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "bordered",
                full_width = FALSE)  %>%
 add_header_above(c("", "Category1" = 3, "Category2" = 3,
                           "Category3" = 3, "Category4" = 2)) %>%
  collapse_rows(columns = 1,
                valign = "middle")
```

-output

[image]

---

Some of the styling can be changed as well

```
mtcars %>%
   kable() %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "responsive",
                full_width = FALSE)  %>%
 add_header_above(c("", "Category1" = 3, "Category2" = 3,
                           "Category3" = 3, "Category4" = 2)) %>%
  collapse_rows(columns = 1,
                valign = "middle")
```

Comment: Thanks! Any solution with formattable though? I wanted to use it on a current table that has arrows for some columns that i've implemented using the library formattable

Comment: @user3742304 i use `formattable` a lot and it is a good package, but in certain situations with multiple column headers `kableExtra` or `gt` seems more easier to created.  Or else in formattable, you can create multiple headers by `paste` or `str_wrap` with `sep` as `\n`, but it may not look that good as in kableExtra